# Ajax calls to webmethod in aspx page for flexigrid

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flexigrid

I'm trying to populate a flexigrid (jquery plugin) using a webmethod from my page (not web service).

My problem is that my webmethod doesn't run (i put a breakpoint in it and it is not hit) unless I'm making the ajax call specifying content-type: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` . Otherwise the call will just return the full page.

The plugin is making a post request with data formatted like this 
**page=1&rp=15..**. and my web method will give an error saying that "*Invalid Json primitive: page*",

So, modifying the plugin is the only way for me to make this work with a webmethod? (I'm not very experienced in jquery and I'll avoid to modify it as much as possible)

Please, if you have any suggestions, help me. Thank you!